# Swift Quick/Nimble - Wait for predicate to match

Tags: ios, swift, quick-nimble

I'm trying to convert the following block of code to Quick/Nimble with no success whatsoever

```swift
XCTWaiter().wait(for: [XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "height == 0"), 
                                                 object: vc.myView.frame)], 
                 timeout: 1)
```

I tried the following but the test does not pass

```swift
waitUntil(timeout: 2) { done in
    expect(vc.myView.frame.height).to(equal(0))
    done()
}
```

Thx in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, what is the purpose of using a 2 sec timeout? Also, what is the error?

Comment: Well it was previously set to 1 and its purpose is to wait for a dropdown view to close, thus the `height == 0`

Comment: It would be nice to see more code unless my answer has helped you already :)

Comment: The rest is kinda sensitive but really it's all the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set the timeout globally, e.g. once your tests start, so it applies for all `toEventually` calls:

#### Nimble >= 9.0.0

```swift
Nimble.AsyncDefaults.timeout = .seconds(2)
```

#### Nimble < 9.0.0

```swift
Nimble.AsyncDefaults.Timeout = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

I think "toEventually" is what you are looking for. Here is the example:

```
expect(vc.myView.frame.height).toEventually(equal(0), timeout: 2)
```

More to check here: https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#asynchronous-expectations